# Using JSoup, can you get the position/index of a node in the html?

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

Once JSoup has parsed an html String, can you go from the Node object to the start/end String indexes?

I think this isn't possible. But perhaps someone has tried editing JSoup to expose this information? 
Or has another solution to matching Nodes onto Strings?

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only position you can get from jsoup are [elementSiblingIndex](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#elementSiblingIndex%28%29) and [siblingIndex](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#siblingIndex%28%29). Possible you can calculate something with them, but not shure if that's a good idea.

Can you give some more information about what you want to do? Maybe there's another solution for your problem.

Comment: I want to annotate a String (holding the page html in this case) with information about interesting substrings.

Comment: Not as cleanly. Suppose you have a region of the String which starts half-way through one <p> tag, then ends half-way through the next <p>.